# ajax is not working in codeigniter view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i'm working with CodeIgniter, and i'm trying to send form data to a controller with AJAX.
The problem is that when i try to get the datas in the controller by using $this->input->get_post("sku_qty"), the content of it is NULL. ajax is also getting error.
 here's the code:

container_view_2.php

```
    <?php
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    ?>
    <html>
<head>

  <link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 text-primary">
      <center>
        <h2>Container calculator</h2>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2  col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
          <label>Partner Name</label>
          <select id="partners" name="partnername" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                    <option value="Amazon">Amazon.com</option>
                                    <option value="Homedepot">Homedepot.com</option>
                                    <option value="Build">Build.com</option>
                                </select>
        </div>


      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2  col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
          <label>SKU</label>
          <select id="sku" name="sku" class="form-control selectpicker">
                                    <option value="Build">Build</option>
                                    <option value="Homedepot">Homedepot</option>
                                    <option value="Amazon">Amazon</option>
                                </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
          <label>Qty</label>
          <input type="number" name="sku_qty" id="sku_qty" placeholder="Enter the qty" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
          <label>Start Port Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="spname" id="spname" placeholder="start port name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
          <label>End Port Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="epname" id="epname" placeholder="end port name" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-7  col-lg-offset-7 col-sm-offset-7 form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1"><button type="submit" onclick="calculateContainerdata()" class="btn btn-primary">CALCULATE</button></div>
          <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2"></div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

  </div>
  <div class="container" style="margin-top: 1em">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Nested Box Container</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <?php
                                //echo $partners;
                                ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Boxed Container Info</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table class="table table-responsive text-center">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Container Size</th>
                <th scope="col">SKU Qty</th>
                <th scope="col">Cost</th>
                <th scope="col">container qty</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>40"</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td>1</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>20"</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>1600</td>
                <td>2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>18"</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>1800</td>
                <td>3</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>10"</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>1900</td>
                <td>5</td>
              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'); ?>"></script>
  <script>
    function calculateContainerdata() {

      var partners = $('#partners :selected').val();
      var sku = $('#sku :selected').val();
      var sku_qty = $('#sku_qty').val();
      var spname = $('#spname').val();
      var epname = $('#epname').val();
      alert(partners);
      var url = "<?php echo site_url('container/calcajax'); ?>";
      alert(url);
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          partners: partners,
          sku: sku,
          sku_qty: sku_qty,
          spname: spname,
          epname: epname,
          url: url
        },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(rdata) {
          alert(rdata);
          //window.location.href = '<?php //echo site_url("index");  ?>';
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          alert("error" + xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
  </script>



</body>

</html>
```

my controller is :
   Container.php

```
        <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    /* 
     * container calculator view
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    class Container extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();  
            $this->load->helper('url');
        }

        public function index() {


            $this->load->view('container_view_2');
           // $this->load->view('container_view');

            //echo 'pramod';
        }

        public function calcajax() {
            $partners = $this->input->post('sku_qty');
             echo json_encode($partners);
            exit();


        }

    }
```

Comment: How do you know what's in `$partners`? Your ajax is requesting json and you aren't returning valid json so the success callback will not be called and error callback will

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is actually sent

Comment: @charlietfl but in success function not printing any data,

Comment: It won't if you request json and return html

Comment: @charlietfl  i edited my contoller function. but same error occures.

Comment: @santosh are you sure AJAX request hitting your controller method?

Comment: @AbdullaNilam but getting form data with ajax passes to the controller function but it's not working..plese help

Comment: what you mean buy this **function but it's not working**

Comment: @AbdullaNilam  ajax function is not working is getting error

Comment: post the error message '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162991/discussion-between-santosh-and-abdulla-nilam).

Answer (score 0):

The response is in the wrong form. Try this

```
public function calcajax()
{
    $partners = $this->input->post('sku_qty');
    if(isset($partners)) //not null
    {
        $out = ['sku_qty' => $partners];
    }
    else
    {
        $out = ['sku_qty' => 0];
    }
    echo json_encode($out);
    //exit(); Just let CodeIgniter do its thing
}
```

In addition to responding with the correct data structure it also makes sure the returned value is useful.

If you're still getting the error response then it's most likely because the ajax url is wrong. Use your browser's dev tool to see what data was actually posted and to where.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `datatype` tag from ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      partners: partners,
      sku: sku,
      sku_qty: sku_qty,
      spname: spname,
      epname: epname,
      url: url
    },
    success: function(rdata) {
      alert(rdata);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      alert("error" + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
```

and also remove `json_encode()` from your controller function